# how to scrape through drop down menu using requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to scrape through web pages that are selected from drop down as shown below

```
 <h1>Scraping Test</h1>
    <form action="/tests/scraping" method='post'>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="1499585369##d2d1570f820aec0589b3bd5f4ab4e7df913e25ff"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Ward: </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="ward">
                        <option value=''>-- select --</option>
                        <option value='DHANLAXMICOMPLEX'>DHANLAXMICOMPLEX</option>
                        <option value='POTALIYA'>POTALIYA</option>
                        <option value='ARJUNTOWER'>ARJUNTOWER</option>
                        <option value='NEWCLOTHMARKET'>NEWCLOTHMARKET</option>
                        <option value='CHANAKYAPURI'>CHANAKYAPURI</option>
                        <option value='BHAIKAKANAGAR'>BHAIKAKANAGAR</option>
                        <option value='RADHASWAMYROAD'>RADHASWAMYROAD</option>
                        <option value='SATADHAR'>SATADHAR</option>
                        <option value='AMRUTAVIDYALAYA'>AMRUTAVIDYALAYA</option>
                        <option value='AGARWALTOWERS'>AGARWALTOWERS</option>
                        <option value='RANNAPARK'>RANNAPARK</option>
                        <option value='IIM'>IIM</option>
                        <option value='VEJALPURWARD'>VEJALPURWARD</option>
                        <option value='GITAMANDIR'>GITAMANDIR</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Search" class="search"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

how to request a webpage from that drop down menu and there is also a search button
my code

```
import requests, csv
from lxml import html

def get_all_pages():

   payload = {'value':'DHANLAXMICOMPLEX'}
   url = requests.get('https://recruitment.advarisk.com/tests/scraping',data=payload)
   print(url.text)
```

Comment: Share code you've already tried

Comment: i have added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a token value which you can get from this `HTML` element

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="1499585369##d2d1570f820aec0589b3bd5f4ab4e7df913e25ff"/>
```

and use in your request. Try to use below code and let me know in case of any issues

```
import lxml.html
import requests

url = "https://recruitment.advarisk.com/tests/scraping"
s = requests.session()
r = s.get(url)
source = lxml.html.document_fromstring(r.content)
token = source.xpath('//input[@name="csrf_token"]/@value')[0]

headers = {'Referer': 'https://recruitment.advarisk.com/tests/scraping'}
data = {'csrf_token': token, 'ward': 'DHANLAXMICOMPLEX'}

print(s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers).text)
```

Comment: is there any way you could comment what exactly is happening? I'm not able to follow, inexperienced in this area.

Comment: @CleveGreen , this is the way how to get token value from one request and pass it to another as header. This might not be applicable to your exact case. You might need to submit new ticket regarding your issue